# Is it acceptable to ask the user to install ALL the windows update before running my application?

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, installation

I have a wpf application which requires .net 4 client. 
I found that it crashes on a clean win7sp1 installation, but if I install all the updates (for windows 7 and for .net 4), my application runs very well.

So can I make a requirement that the user should install all windows updates?

The ideal requirement should be: win7 sp1, + kb2345xxx; but I don't know which kb is the the root cause of the fix of crash.

I don't see applications which requires all windows update, and I'm not sure if it's acceptable for the users.

Comment: What you are describing are called the prerequisites for your application. During the installation procedure, it is common to see popup windows alerting the user to these prerequisites for different software, so I see no problem with you setting them as prerequisites... if you're application needs them to work, then what else can you do apart from rewrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but as far as I'm concerned Windows 7 doesn't include the .Net Framework 4.0, it ships with the .Net Framework 3.5

Furthermore, the SP1 doesn't include any .Net Framework upgrade, just hotfixes for the .Net framework 3.5. If your app requires a specific version of the .Net framework, then there's nothing you can do to make it run on lower versions, what you can do is add a check in the installer with some information about the required version of the framework so it fails gracefully rather than crashing

To answer your question, asking the user to download all updates is ok for an enterprise application. But, if you are targeting general users, then don't do that, many users have no technical knowledge whatsoever and will just ditch your app on the spot.

#### Resources

[Windows versions vs.Net Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework#Versions)

[What's included in Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (SP1)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows7/whats-included-in-windows-7-service-pack-1-sp1)

Comment: Oh yes, after your note I checked and realized that I was confused between 'supported' and 'pre-installed' for a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

If your application requires .NET 4.0 with some other pre-requisites you might want to declare the required as Prerequisites while building your Setup and deployment project . Eg : [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/7eh4aaa5(v=vs.100).aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35976/Add-Prerequisites-of-NET-Framework-in-Visual-Studi)

The framework and any custom prerequisites can also be handled either by downloading from the vendor website or creating it yourself.